# Removing Square Brackets and Double quotes from list

Tags: python

I need to remove Square brackets and Double quotes from python list for further processing of data.

My code for the same is as follows:

```
ips = ['1.2.3.5','1.2.3.4']
y = []

for ip in ips:
        x = "model.data.like('%"+ip+"%'),"
        y.append([x])
print y
```

So here final result which I got is as follows:

```
["model.data.like('%1.2.3.5%'),"], ["model.data.like('%1.2.3.4%'),"]
```

Now here I need to get rid of square brackets and double quotes.

I need the output as follows:

```
model.data.like('%1.2.3.5%'),model.data.like('%1.2.3.4%')
```

Please have a note that IP address is dynamic one, List can contain more than two IP addresses.

Comment: `y` is a list. `print y` causes python to print a human-readable string representation of the list. The square brackets are a visual hint that its a list and the double quotes are a visual hint that they are strings. Neither the brackets nor the outer quotes are actually part of the data.

Comment: Thanks Understood your point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `flattening list` and `join`function-

```
>>>t=[item for sublist in y for item in sublist]
>>print t
>>>["model.data.like('%1.2.3.5%'),", "model.data.like('%1.2.3.4%'),"]
>>>data =  ''.join(t)
>>>print data
>>>model.data.like('%1.2.3.5%'),model.data.like('%1.2.3.4%'),
>>>cleaned_data = data.rstrip(',')
>>>print cleaned_data
>>>model.data.like('%1.2.3.5%'),model.data.like('%1.2.3.4%')
```

Comment: Thank you, But it gives result as follows: model.data.like('%1.2.3.5%'),,model.data.like('%1.2.3.4%'),
Here I don't need ,, I need only one comma there.
As well as If I can be able to get rid of final , It will be much better

Comment: I think OP should remove the commas in his list items and use `'"'.join(t)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use formatting the string by accessing the element of `list`.

```
In [58]: s = ''

In [59]: for i in ips:
    s = s + "model.data.like (%{}%),".format(i)

In [72]: s[:-1]
Out[72]: 'model.data.like (%1.2.3.5%),model.data.like (%1.2.3.4%)'
```

Answer (score 1):

So, you do want to make a string from list? That's simple, you can use `str.join` to do this:

```
ips = ['1.2.3.5','1.2.3.4']

# this is list comprehension, it does the same thing as your loop
y = ["model.data.like('%"+ip+"%')" for ip in ips]

print  ','.join(y)
```